# PDFKitten analogues

Tags: ios, objective-c

[PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten) is a pdf text search framework for objective-c/ios. But it supports only latin characters. Is where an alternative with non-latin symbols support?

Answer (score 1):

You can check these alternative

[FastPdfKit](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit)

[Random thoughts](http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184)

[libharu](https://github.com/libharu/libharu)

Comment: Have you tried this libs? FastPdfKit is big pdf reader framework - it is overkill for pdf search. Also it is not fully free for use - free with a splash screen only. And Random thoughts solution seems to haven't non-latin characters support. Anyway, I'll try two last alternatives, thanks.

Comment: Also libharu is a pdf generation library, it seems to hasn't search functionality at all